# VBA, Application-defined or Object Error, changing Pivot Filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the pivot filter using vba based on a cell.
I get error `Application-defined or Object Error` on my second line of code.

```
Sub RefreshPivots()

Sheets("Details").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Details").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh


temp = Sheets("Input").Range("H2")
Sheets("Details").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Period").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=temp

  

End Sub
```

I am trying to switch to a date that I have in `Sheets("Input").Range("H2")` So if I have Sept 10/20 in this cell, I want the pivot to update to that.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Pivot Fields:

[image]

Pivot source data, maybe this format could be why?

[image]

**filterDate value based on Christians Code:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the value of `temp` when this fails?

Comment: `SEP 03/20` which is the date I am trying to change the pivot too.

Comment: Is that the text `SEP 03/20` or a date that has formatting applied to it?

Comment: Formatting as a "Date"

Comment: Untested, but maybe try a type like `xlSpecificDate` instead of `xlCaptionEquals`... might be misleading you though, not sure.

Comment: `the date you entered is not a valid date. Please try again`

Comment: I haven't worked with Pivot Tables through VBA before. But don't you need to `Set temp = ...` because it's a reference to a range? Or pull out the `.Value` if you want it as a string?

Comment: try `temp = Format(Sheets("Input").Range("H2"),"MMM dd/yy")`. The format of `temp` must equal the format of the data behind the pivot table. Otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Still getting error. the temp value is `Sep 03/20`

Comment: What is the datatype of the underlying data? Maybe assign the cell in the underlying data in a variable and see what comes back? Try different variable types (date/string/etc) and see how it behaves until you are able to get a match in the code. It has to work in some way, but it's hard to give an exact answer without actually have the file you are using. Also, use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code and explicitly state the variable type for `temp`.

Comment: It looks like you are storing the Date as an numeric value. Try using `Dim filterDate as Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think the `Period` field must be under the *Rows* section of the *PivotTable Fields* pane (alone or among other fields - order doesn't matter):
[image]

Then you would need to replace this:

```
temp = Sheets("Input").Range("H2")
Sheets("Details").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Period").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=temp
```

with this:

```
With Sheets("Details").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Period")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=Sheets("Input").Range("H2").Value2
End With
```

---

You might want to do some checks before running your code because sheet names can change as well as pivot table names and so on. Also instead of `Sheets` maybe use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`. This way you are not reffering to the ActiveWorkbook but to the Workbook where the code is running.

**EDIT**

Here's code that does some checks like mentioned above:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RefreshPivots()
    Dim pivTable1 As PivotTable
    Dim pivTable2 As PivotTable
    
    Set pivTable1 = GetPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, "Details", "PivotTable1")
    If pivTable1 Is Nothing Then
        'Do Something. Maybe Exit or display a MsgBox
    End If
    pivTable1.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Set pivTable2 = GetPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, "Details", "PivotTable2")
    If pivTable2 Is Nothing Then
        'Do Something. Maybe Exit or display a MsgBox
    End If
    pivTable2.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Dim periodField As PivotField
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set periodField = pivTable1.PivotFields("Period")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If periodField Is Nothing Then
        'Do Something. Maybe Exit or display a MsgBox
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim filterDate As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next
    filterDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs").Range("H2").Value2
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Do Something. Maybe Exit or display a MsgBox
    Else
        Select Case VarType(filterDate)
        Case vbDouble
            'Maybe check if serial number is valid
        Case vbString
            filterDate = CDbl(CDate(filterDate))
        Case Else
            'Maybe show a MsgBox
            Exit Sub
        End Select
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With periodField
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=filterDate
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetPivotTable(ByVal sourceBook As Workbook _
    , ByVal wSheetName As String _
    , ByVal pivotName As String _
) As PivotTable
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetPivotTable = sourceBook.Worksheets(wSheetName).PivotTables(pivotName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**EDIT 2**

I've simplified the filter date check and added some code instead of the "Maybe" comments:

```
Sub RefreshPivots()
    Dim pivTable1 As PivotTable
    Dim pivTable2 As PivotTable
    
    Set pivTable1 = GetPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, "Details", "PivotTable1")
    If pivTable1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Table", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    pivTable1.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Set pivTable2 = GetPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, "Details", "PivotTable2")
    If pivTable2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Table", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    pivTable2.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Dim periodField As PivotField
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set periodField = pivTable1.PivotFields("Period")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If periodField Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Field", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Maybe check if date is within a certain range
'    If filterDate < minDate Or filterDate > maxDate Then
'        MsgBox "Invalid Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
'        Exit Sub
'    End If

    Dim filterDate As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next
    filterDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs").Range("H2").Value2
    If VarType(filterDate) = vbString Then filterDate = CDbl(CDate(filterDate))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Or VarType(filterDate) <> vbDouble Then
        MsgBox "Missing/Invalid Filter Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Err.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With periodField
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=filterDate
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT 3**

Based on updated question:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RefreshPivots()
    Dim pivTable1 As PivotTable
    Dim pivTable2 As PivotTable
    
    Set pivTable1 = GetPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, "Details", "PivotTable1")
    If pivTable1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Table", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    pivTable1.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Set pivTable2 = GetPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, "Details", "PivotTable2")
    If pivTable2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Table", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    pivTable2.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Dim periodField As PivotField
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set periodField = pivTable1.PivotFields("Period")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If periodField Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Field", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    periodField.ClearAllFilters
    
    'Maybe check if date is within a certain range
'    If filterDate < minDate Or filterDate > maxDate Then
'        MsgBox "Invalid Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
'        Exit Sub
'    End If

    Dim filterDate As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next
    filterDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs").Range("H2").Value2
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "Missing Filter Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Try String first
    If VarType(filterDate) = vbString Then
        periodField.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=filterDate
        If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        filterDate = CDbl(CDate(filterDate))
        Err.Clear
    End If
    
    If VarType(filterDate) <> vbDouble Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Filter Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Try Date (as Double data type)
    periodField.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=filterDate
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "Could not apply filter", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetPivotTable(ByVal sourceBook As Workbook _
    , ByVal wSheetName As String _
    , ByVal pivotName As String _
) As PivotTable
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetPivotTable = sourceBook.Worksheets(wSheetName).PivotTables(pivotName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Cristian. I am getting `The date you entered is not a valid date` on line `.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=filterDate` .  The value of `filterDate` does equal `SEP 10/20` which is in the Period drop down row. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @excelguy Try a ```Debug.Print VarType(filterDate)```. It should be a 5 (vbDouble) - check the Immediate window. If you get an 8 (vbString) then try casting to double using ```CDbl(filterDate)```.

Comment: It is a 8. How do I cast it to that? Do you mean when declaring the variable?

Comment: @excelguy I've added a ```Select Case``` statement to the answer and replaced a comment. All the places where I wrote "Maybe" comments are places where you might want to add your own code depending on what you find appropriate for your needs

Comment: @excelguy I've replaced the "Maybe" comments with some code that makes more sense and replaced the ```Select Case```. See **EDIT 2** section. Hope this solves your issue

Comment: thanks Cristian this is really good. Getting the error `Application-defined or object-defined error` on line `.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=filterDate` Do you know why?

Comment: @excelguy I have no idea why you would still get that error. It works fine on the test workbook that I've created for this. It is very difficult to guess what is happening without knowing how the pivot is structured, the data types used, the sheet layout etc.

Comment: Hi Cristian, I've updated with more details, not sure if that will help.

Comment: @excelguy I've added **EDIT 3** section based on your updated question information.

Comment: Thanks Cristian! it works! I have a question, what if "Period" is a filter instead of a "row" , does that change things?

Comment: @excelguy It gets complicated if the field is a filter because you would have to loop through each item in the ```periodField.PivotItems``` and turn it on/off based on the filtering value. You should post a new question for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222245/discussion-between-cristian-buse-and-excelguy).

Answer (score 1):

The filter items in the pivot table are **characters**, not **values**. Therefore, under the condition that the cell format type is the same as the field format type of the pivot table, you must obtain the character, not the cell value(`range("h2").Text` not `range("h2").value`).

```
Sub RefreshPivots()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim PF As PivotField
    Dim Temp As String
    
    Temp = Sheets("Input").Range("H2").Text  '<~~ it is string  not value
    
    Set Ws = Sheets("Details")
    Set PT = Ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set PF = PT.PivotFields("Period")
    

    PT.PivotCache.Refresh
    PF.ClearAllFilters
    
    '*** if your source type is date
    'PF.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=Temp
    'but your source data type is string
    PF.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=Temp
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Dy.Lee .I am getting error `The date you entered is not a valid date` on line `PF.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=Temp` . The value of temp is SEP 10/20 and is in date format in input tab.

Comment: @excelguy, your source data type is text not date. So  `xlSpecificDate`  should be `xlCaptionEquals`  i edited answer.