# VBA, Changing PivotField 'Filter' based on Input value

Tags: excel, vba

Previously I have asked the question on how to change the Pivotfield 'Row' ([VBA, Application-defined or Object Error, changing Pivot Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890590/vba-application-defined-or-object-error-changing-pivot-filter/64053190#64053190)). However it seems like changing the 'Filter' field is different.

Here is my code I use to change the pivottable 'row' value with vba, `Period` being the 'filter' field in my pivot.
When I run it I get an error msg `Could not apply filter` which is user error handling.

```
Dim pivTable1 As PivotTable

    
    Set pivTable1 = GetPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, "Summary of LoBs", "PivotTable1")
    If pivTable1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Table", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    pivTable1.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    
    Dim periodField As PivotField
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set periodField = pivTable1.PivotFields("Period")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If periodField Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Field", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    periodField.ClearAllFilters
    

    

    Dim filterDate As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next
    filterDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("H2").Value2
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "Missing Filter Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Try String first
    If VarType(filterDate) = vbString Then
        periodField.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=filterDate
        If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        filterDate = CDbl(CDate(filterDate))
        Err.Clear
    End If
    
    If VarType(filterDate) <> vbDouble Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Filter Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Try Date (as Double data type)
    periodField.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=filterDate
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "Could not apply filter", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I find it funny that with a username like "excelguy" you forgot the excel tag :-)

Comment: It would be useful to know the actual Err.Number or error message.

Comment: error number is `1004`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a select case that solves both cases (row or field):

```
Sub ApplyFilter()
    Dim pivTable1 As PivotTable

    Set pivTable1 = GetPivotTable(ThisWorkbook, "Summary of LoBs", "PivotTable1")
    If pivTable1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Table", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    pivTable1.PivotCache.Refresh
    
    Dim periodField As PivotField
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set periodField = pivTable1.PivotFields("Period")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If periodField Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Missing Pivot Field", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    periodField.ClearAllFilters
    
    Dim filterDate As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next
    filterDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("H2").Value2
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "Missing Filter Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Select Case periodField.Orientation
    Case xlRowField
        'Try String first
        If VarType(filterDate) = vbString Then
            periodField.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=filterDate
            If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
            
            filterDate = CDbl(CDate(filterDate))
            Err.Clear
        End If
        
        If VarType(filterDate) <> vbDouble Then
            MsgBox "Invalid Filter Date", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'Try Date (as Double data type)
        periodField.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:=filterDate
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            MsgBox "Could not apply filter", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Case xlPageField
        Dim pivItem As PivotItem
        Dim v As Variant
        
        For Each pivItem In periodField.PivotItems
            v = pivItem.Value
            If VarType(v) = VarType(filterDate) Then
                pivItem.Visible = (v = filterDate)
            Else
                'Try converting to date
                If IsDate(v) And IsDate(filterDate) Then
                    pivItem.Visible = (CDate(v) = CDate(filterDate))
                Else
                    'Add other logic based on your needs
                    Err.Raise 5, , "Need more code here"
                End If
            End If
        Next pivItem
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Could not apply filter!" & vbNewLine & "Field must be a <Row> or <Filter> field!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
    End Select
End Sub
```

However, you will see a comment `'Add other logic based on your needs"`. You will need to add logic based on the data types if the code here doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The filter part of the pivot looks like a date format, but your original data is a character that looks like a date.

Although the original data format is a pure date data format, the pivot filter is expressed as text. However, if the original data is a character, `xlCaptionEquals` should be used, and if the original data is a date format, `xlSpecificDate` should be used.

However, all values of **value1** must be in **String** format. Therefore, you need to accurately grasp the format of your original data, and it is recognized as text data in pictures.